# Mysql table rename : is data deleted?

Tags: mysql

I have a table A and another Table B. I rename A as B. Is B's old data cleared from mysql server ?(I am thinking on similar lines to garbage collection of unreferenced variables).

Comment: You can't rename object if another object has the same name. (Exist A, B) -> rename A to B (error).

Answer (score 1):

Renaming a table does not delete the data. It's just an alias. However, if you already have another table with same name then rename operation will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename the table B first (in table C for example), or you will have an error. Your data will be kept on table C.
Then rename your table A.